# Redirect not working on server with header()

Tags: php

I have used the following code for the redirect on URL, but It displaying error 500 error on the server(GoDaddy).

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <input type="submit" class="checkout" name="btnCheckOut" value="PROCEED TO  CHECKOUT" />
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['btnCheckOut']))
        {
            if(isset($empty))
            {
            echo "<script>
                alert('your cart has been empty plese insert some items');
            </script>";
            }
            else
            {
            header("location:Billing.php");
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: There is no issue with the code. check error log..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header function must appear before anything is sent back to the browser.

See http://www.au2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

This is most likely the issue (it is definitely a contributing factor, but it's hard to test if it's the only error.)

Comment: Thanks Using Javascript with Window.href to Solve this